# How to fix jOOQ code generation tool error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.1 with jOOQ codegen tool 3.11.7. I have a Java class configured to slightly modify class names derived from MySQL table names in pom.xml:

```xml
<generator>
  <target>
    <packageName>com.example.foglight.db</packageName>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
  </target>
  <database>
    <excludes>
      flyway_schema_history
      | information_schema.*
    </excludes>
    <inputSchema>${dbName}</inputSchema>
    <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
    <forcedTypes>
      <forcedType>
        <userType>java.util.UUID</userType>
        <binding>com.example.foglight.config.db.MysqlUuidBinding</binding>
        <types>BINARY\(16\)</types>
      </forcedType>
    </forcedTypes>
  </database>
  <generate>
    <deprecationOnUnknownTypes>false</deprecationOnUnknownTypes>
    <pojos>true</pojos>
  </generate>
  <!-- The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style
        Defaults to org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator -->
  <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>
  <!-- The naming strategy used for class and field names.
        You may override this with your custom naming strategy. Some examples follow
        Defaults to org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy -->
  <strategy>
 <name>com.example.foglight.config.db.DatabaseModelNamingStrategy</name>
  </strategy>
</generator>
```

Everything works fine when I'm building/running the app from IntelliJ, however when I run `mvn generate-sources` or `mvn install` from command line in the very same environment, I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.7:generate (default) on project foglight: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: com.example.foglight.config.db.DatabaseModelNamingStrategy -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.7:generate (default) on project foglight: Error running jOOQ code generation tool
```

With detailed explanation below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.foglight.config.db.DatabaseModelNamingStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.loadClass (GenerationTool.java:819)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run (GenerationTool.java:352)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate (GenerationTool.java:220)
    at org.jooq.codegen.maven.Plugin.execute (Plugin.java:197)
```

The class is there (otherwise IntelliJ would be throwing the error too). Is there anything more that IDE is doing under the hood that makes it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jOOQ code generator must have access to your generator strategy via the classpath, which means it has to have been compiled *before* you run the code generator. Since the code generator usually runs *before* the compilation phase of the Maven module that contains it, you will have to extract your generator strategy into another module to make sure it gets compiled before.

Comment: This is really bad designed though. A very common usage of JOOQ is, to put it into a separate java project, where I want to generate all DB related objects in order to use this project as a dependency. 
The current implementation would require me creating an additional project which only contains my naming strategy, which then can be used by the DB-project. Further its inconsistent with how forced types work. Those classes are compiled during the <generate> phase of maven.

Comment: @cobby: There's a certain order of operations in a build. You want logic to be *runnable* at code generation time. This means, it needs to have been compiled prior to that precise moment. Your other example (the forced types) doesn't have this restriction. They don't need to be compiled at that time. They are merely referenced by their qualified class name because you happen to hold this knowledge. There's no bad design in place here, it's just how Maven works.

Comment: I see, but there are use cases where it's rather impractical.

Comment: @cobby: I'm positive that you will give in to Maven's wisdoms rather than fighting it, eventually. I have. After many years :)

Comment: Actually I'm totally agreeing with your post that logic should be runnable at code generation, but it would be nice to have it solved by the jooq maven plugin. Otherwise I have to take the unpleasant route via the compiler-plugin (see my answer to this OP or pull the dependency as a separate module/project).

Comment: @cobby This is a cost / benefit question. There's a big roadmap and we have limited time to invest in this area. Your solution isn't that bad. Neither is creating a new module. It's the Maven way. It's idiomatic. Want to write an XJC plugin to generate some JAXB annotated classes? You'd do the same thing... Any hack that the jOOQ maven compiler plugin would implement would only work to some extent, and when it doesn't, it means maintenance, more unpleasantries, etc. for everyone involved. This is why I said, don't fight Maven. Embrace it. It works very well when not fought.

Answer (score 2):

You could compile and put the class on the classpath as suggested by Lukas Eder. For that, introduce another execution with the maven-compiler-plugin and bind it to the generate-sources phase:

```
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <executions>
         <execution>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
              </goals>
             <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <includes>
                   <include>tb/database/jooq/custom/namingstrategies/*.java</include>
                </includes>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
```